# when checkbox is checked it calculate the price but the issue it not appear in confirm

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function fuelPrice()
{
    var fuelPrice=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["price"];
    var withFuelPrice = document.getElementsByClassName("ful");
    if(withFuelPrice.checked==true)
    {
        fuelPrice=30;
    }
    return fuelPrice;
}

function withPol()
{
    var polishPrice=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["price"];
    var includeInscription = document.getElementsByClassName("pol");
    if(includeInscription.checked==true){
        polishPrice=50;
    }
    return polishPrice;
}

function driver()
{
    var driverPrice=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["price"];
    var getDriv = document.getElementsByClassName("drv");
    if(getDriv.checked==true){
        driverPrice=50;
    }
    return driverPrice;
}

function calculateTotal()
{
var car1= 50
    var total = fuelPrice() + withPol() + car1 + driver();
     var text = "Total Price For the Renting "+total+ "BHD/Week";
    //display the result
    var divobj = document.getElementsByClassName('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = text;
  
    return text;

}

function myFunction()
{
 var name = calculateTotal()
 confirm(name)
}
```

```html
<form class="price"><p class="totalPrice booktxt">Total Price For the Renting 50BHD/Week<br> </p>
                <input onclick="calculateTotal() " type="checkbox" class="ful">With Fuel<br>
                <input onclick="calculateTotal() " type="checkbox" class="pol">Polishing 2 weeks<br>
                <input onclick="calculateTotal() " type="checkbox" class="drv">Driver<br>

                </form>
                <button class="btn1" onclick="myFunction()">Add to cart</button>
```

I am having some issues to make the price appear in confirm so the user sees the price and confirm its ok or not when i click it show a blank popup. Also, can I know my mistake to avoid it in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return something to show in that confirm box.

```js
function fuelPrice() {
  var fuelPrice = 0;
  var theForm = document.forms["price"];
  var withFuelPrice = theForm.elements["ful"];
  if (withFuelPrice.checked == true) {
    fuelPrice = 30;
  }
  return fuelPrice;
}

function withPol() {
  var polishPrice = 0;
  var theForm = document.forms["price"];
  var includeInscription = theForm.elements["pol"];
  if (includeInscription.checked == true) {
    polishPrice = 50;
  }
  return polishPrice;
}

function driver() {
  var driverPrice = 0;
  var theForm = document.forms["price"];
  var getDriv = theForm.elements["drv"];
  if (getDriv.checked == true) {
    driverPrice = 50;
  }
  return driverPrice;
}

function calculateTotal() {
  var car1 = 50
  var total = fuelPrice() + withPol() + car1 + driver();
  var text = "Total Price For the Renting " + total + "BHD/Week"; // Store text in local variable

  //display the result
  var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
  divobj.style.display = 'block';
  divobj.innerHTML = text;

  return text; // Return text
}

function myFunction() {
  var name = calculateTotal()
  confirm(name) // Now it shows text from calculateTotal function
}
```

```html
<form id="price">
  <p id="totalPrice" class="booktxt">Total Price For the Renting 50BHD/Week<br> </p>
  <input onclick="calculateTotal() " type="checkbox" id="ful">With Fuel<br>
  <input onclick="calculateTotal() " type="checkbox" id="pol">Polishing 2 weeks<br>
  <input onclick="calculateTotal() " type="checkbox" id="drv">Driver<br>
</form>
<button class="btn1" onclick="myFunction()">Add to cart</button>
```

Comment: Mark my answer as accepted so future visitors will know that this question is answered properly. And I'm glad I helped.

Comment: var getDriv = theForm.elements["drv"];
this line is only vaild for id how i can make useable for class

Comment: Using `getElementsByClassName` method.

Comment: That's because `getElementsByClassName` returns NodeList, collection of nodes. Read more about that and ask new question as that one isn't related anymore to your original problem.

Comment: sorry but i need to wait 90min for asking another

Answer (score 0):

- Just add a return value to calculateTotal function. Like the following

  ```
  return divobj.innerHTML;
  ```
- Full function looks as follows:

  ```
  function calculateTotal()
  {
      var car1= 50
      var total = fuelPrice() + withPol() + car1 + driver();

      //display the result
      var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
      divobj.style.display='block';
      divobj.innerHTML = "Total Price For the Renting "+total+ "BHD/Week";
      return divobj.innerHTML;
  }
  ```

Comment: sorry, the question was answered while I was adding mine.